# MemoryError while trying to using itertools.permutations, how use less memory?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

I'm loading from a text document containing so random strings and I'm trying to print every possible permutation of the characters in that string.

If the notepad contains for example:

```
123
abc
```

I want my output to be

```
123,132,213,231,312,321
abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba
```

The text file contains some pretty large strings so I can see why I am getting this MemoryError.

My first attempt I used this:

```
import sys
import itertools
import math

def organize(to_print):
    number_list = []
    upper_list = []
    lower_list = []
    for x in range(0,len(to_print)):
        if str(to_print[x]).isdigit() is True:
            number_list.append(to_print[x])
        elif to_print[x].isupper() is True:
            upper_list.append(to_print[x])
        else:
            lower_list.append(to_print[x])
    master_list = number_list + upper_list + lower_list
    return master_list

number = open(*file_dir*, 'r').readlines()

factorial = math.factorial(len(number))
complete_series = ''

for x in range(0,factorial):
    complete_string = ''.join((list(itertools.permutations(organize(number)))[x]))

    complete_series += complete_string+','
edit_series = complete_series[:-1]
print(edit_series)
```

The reason for `def organize` is if I have a string `1aB` I would need to preorder it by number,uppercase,lowercase before I start the permutations.

I got the memory error here: `complete_string = ''.join((list(itertools.permutations(organize(number)))[x]))` so my initial attempt was to bring it out of the for-loop.

---

My second attempt is this:

```
import sys
import itertools
import math

def organize(to_print):
    number_list = []
    upper_list = []
    lower_list = []
    for x in range(0,len(to_print)):
        if str(to_print[x]).isdigit() is True:
            number_list.append(to_print[x])
        elif to_print[x].isupper() is True:
            upper_list.append(to_print[x])
        else:
            lower_list.append(to_print[x])
    master_list = number_list + upper_list + lower_list
    return master_list

number = open(*file_dir*, 'r').readlines()

factorial = math.factorial(len(number))
complete_series = ''
the_permutation = list(itertools.permutations(organize(number)))

for x in range(0,factorial):
    complete_string = ''.join((the_permutation[x]))

    complete_series += complete_string+','
edit_series = complete_series[:-1]
print(edit_series)
```

But I am still getting a memory error. I don't necessarily need or want the answer directly as this is good learning practice to reduce my inefficiencies, so hints in the right direction would be nice.

---

Added 3rd attempt:

```
import sys
import itertools
import math

def organize(to_print):
    number_list = []
    upper_list = []
    lower_list = []
    for x in range(0,len(to_print)):
        if str(to_print[x]).isdigit() is True:
            number_list.append(to_print[x])
        elif to_print[x].isupper() is True:
            upper_list.append(to_print[x])
        else:
            lower_list.append(to_print[x])
    master_list = number_list + upper_list + lower_list
    return master_list

number = open(*file_dir*, 'r').readlines()

factorial = math.factorial(len(number))
complete_series = ''
the_permutation = itertools.permutations(organize(number))
for x in itertools.islice(the_permutation,factorial):
    complete_string = ''.join(next(the_permutation))
    complete_series += complete_string+','
edit_series = complete_series[:-1]
print(edit_series)
```

Comment: You are exploding all possible permutations into a list. Are you *sure* you need to have random access to all possible permutations?

Comment: I think the number of permutations is somewhat larger than you think. Suppose you have 1 a4 of text. Then amidst all permutations are all possible poems in english, german and french that were ever written...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call list, just iterate over the permutations:

```
the_permutation = itertools.permutations(organize(number))

for x in the_permutation:
    complete_string = ''.join(the_permutation)
```

`list(itertools.permutations(organize(number)))` stores all the permutations in memory then you store all the permutations in a string in your loop, there is no guarantee that you will be able to store all the data even using this approach depending on how much data is in `the_permutation`

If you only want a certain amount of the permutations you can call next om the permutations object:

```
the_permutation = itertools.permutations(organize(number))
for x in range(factorial):
    complete_string = ''.join(next(the_permutation))
```

Or use itertools.islice:

```
for x in itertools.islice(the_permutation,factorial):
    complete_string = ''.join(next(the_permutation))
```

Comment: I tried this before considering the list might be the issue, here is my error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question.py", line 27, in <module>
    complete_string = ''.join(the_permutation)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found`

I'll try to see where i can go with this though.

Comment: That is because you are trying to join tuples, iterating over then joining each tuple is not the same as calling join on the permutations object

Comment: What does it mean if I'm getting this?
`Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.` I'm assuming the int is too big for `islice()` to support it in that case?

Comment: @AndyWong, most probably yes, what is factorial?

Comment: pretty large, my practice question changes the textfile each run through but its always a huge number. I was considering nested if statements where I separated the permutations of numbers, upper_case, and lower_case characters separately to reduce the number. Other than that I'm assuming I need to code the factorial manually and call each instance individually to save memory

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to break up the permutations somehow but again depending on how larger the size of your input is going to be then there is no guarantee it is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind factorials grow enormously fast

[image]

... so even for a string of moderate length the number of permutations is enormous. For 12 letters its ~ 480 million.