# Python: itertools.product consuming too much resources

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I've created a Python script that generates a list of words by permutation of characters. I'm using `itertools.product` to generate my permutations. My char list is composed by letters and numbers **01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ**. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import itertools, hashlib, math

class Words:

    chars = '01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ'

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.make(size)

    def getLenght(self, size):
        res = []
        for i in range(1, size+1):
            res.append(math.pow(len(self.chars), i))
        return sum(res)

    def getMD5(self, text):
        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update(text.encode('utf-8'))
        return m.hexdigest()

    def make(self, size):
        file = open('res.txt', 'w+')
        res = []
        i = 1
        for i in range(1, size+1):
            prod = list(itertools.product(self.chars, repeat=i))
            res = res + prod
        j = 1
        for r in res:
            text = ''.join(r)
            md5 = self.getMD5(text)
            res = text+'\t'+md5
            print(res + ' %.3f%%' % (j/float(self.getLenght(size))*100))
            file.write(res+'\n')
            j = j + 1
        file.close()

Words(3)
```

This script works fine for list of words with max 4 characters. If I try 5 or 6 characters, my computer consumes 100% of CPU, 100% of RAM and freezes.

Is there a way to restrict the use of those resources or optimize this heavy processing?

Comment: Your problem is calling list, which then evaluates all of them. Itertools is great for iteration **lazily**, evaluating them 1-by-1 to avoid memory issues. You're trying nearly 1 billion combinations at 5 characters (62**5), which is why your computer freezes. It's literally consuming all the available memory.

Comment: Your suggestion is to iterate manualy?

Comment: I'll post a solution. You should iterate over each element. Itertools works similar to yield, (although lower level), but you can think of it like this: it is given a set of instructions, it then evaluates one value, and returns it and freezes (so no memory buildup). You can then do whatever, until you need the next element. Putting all immediately in memory defeats the purpose of using itertools, especially for data sizes like this (~38 gigs of ram).

You should evaluate each element as it's generated, do work for each, and then keep only what you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503388/prevent-memory-error-in-itertools-permutation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303610/memoryerror-while-trying-to-using-itertools-permutations-how-use-less-memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

I've made all the changes in the make method:

```
def make(self, size):

    with open('res.txt', 'w+') as file_: # file is a builtin function in python 2
        # also, use with statements for files used on only a small block, it handles file closure even if an error is raised.
        for i in range(1, size+1):
            prod = itertools.product(self.chars, repeat=i)

            for j, r in enumerate(prod):
                text = ''.join(r)
                md5 = self.getMD5(text)
                res = text+'\t'+md5
                print(res + ' %.3f%%' % ((j+1)/float(self.get_length(size))*100))
                file_.write(res+'\n')
```

Be warned this will still chew up gigabytes of memory, but not virtual memory.

EDIT: As noted by Padraic, there is no **file** keyword in Python 3, and as it is a "bad builtin", it's not too worrying to override it. Still, I'll name it file_ here.

EDIT2:

To explain why this works so much faster and better than the previous, original version, you need to know how **lazy** evaluation works.

Say we have a simple expression as follows (for Python 3) (use xrange for Python 2):

```
a = [i for i in range(1e12)]
```

This immediately evaluates 1 trillion elements into memory, overflowing your memory.

So we can use a generator to solve this:

```
a = (i for i in range(1e12))
```

Here, none of the values have been evaluated, just given the interpreter instructions on how to evaluate it. We can then iterate through each item **one by one** and do work on each separately, so almost nothing is in memory at a given time (only 1 integer at a time). This makes the seemingly impossible task very manageable.

The same is true with itertools: it allows you to do memory-efficient, fast operations by using iterators rather than lists or arrays to do operations.

In your example, you have 62 characters and want to do the cartesian product with 5 repeats, or 62**5 (nearly a billion elements, or over 30 gigabytes of ram). This is prohibitively large."

In order to solve this, we can use iterators.

```
chars = '01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ'
for i in itertools.product(chars, repeat=5):
    print(i)
```

Here, only a single item from the cartesian product is in memory at a given time, meaning it is very memory efficient.

However, if you evaluate the full iterator using list(), it then exhausts the iterator and adds it to a list, meaning the nearly one billion combinations are suddenly in memory again. We don't need all the elements in memory at once: just 1. Which is the power of iterators.

Here are links to the [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and another explanation on [iterators in Python 2](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) (mostly true for 3).

Comment: There is no file function in python3

Comment: True, but since it's tagged with the ambiguous tag Python, it could Python2 or 3.  Anyway, the with statement should be done either way.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I'll accept your answer. The script worked well. Could you explain what you've changed and why wasn't working?

Comment: Edited, let me know if you want any more clarification. I tried to explain iterators, and added a few external resources.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! You helped a lot.  :D